# Smart Life + IFTTT + Google Assistant trigger via Webhooks

Tags: google-smart-home, ifttt, google-assistant

**Problem**

I bought these LED's lights off Amazon that you setup with Smart Life, which has Google/Alexa/IFTTT integration.  Which is great but when I go to IFTTT and I try to setup a webhooks to trigger the lights turning on IFTTT says the devices are not compatible and to check with the manufacturer (IFTTT has Smart Life compatibility but apparently not all devices are).  I have sent out a request to the manufacturer about compatibility with IFTTT, but in the mean time I'm trying to brain storm of a way to get this to work.

**Goal**

I have an NFT scanner program running on Python that I would like to have the NFT scanner hit a webhook URL and it trigger changing these Smart Life lights to a certain color.  Is there any other way to do this given that it does work with Google Assistant and is setup in my Google Home?

Lights for reference: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07VZM3BJZ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VZM3BJZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with the non-compatible SmartLife stuff is to create separate Tap-to-Run tasks in SmartLife for turning the equipment ON and OFF.  IFTTT can access the Tap-to-Runs even when it cannot access the asset itself.  Remember to update the link to SmartLife to include the newest additions.

Name the tasks in a logical manner because you will be getting a lot of them.  Something like *SL Porch ON* works for me.